# Generic interface implementation confusion

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I'm getting myself in a bit of a mess regarding interface implementations, all my attempted 'fixes' seem to make the whole solution more complex and broken. I'm sure there is a simple answer, but I can't quite see it at the moment!

I have these two interfaces (the second is used in a list of the first):

```
public interface IUserDefinedListEditViewModel<T> where T : IUserDefinedListEntryEditViewModel<IBaseUserDefinedListModel>
{
    string TypeName { get; set; }
    IList<T> UserDefinedListEntries { get; set; }
}

public interface IUserDefinedListEntryEditViewModel<T> where T : IBaseUserDefinedListModel
{
    string Display { get; set; }
    T UserDefinedListEntry { get; set; }
}
```

I have a third interface which is implemented by several different classes:

```
public interface IBaseUserDefinedListModel
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    bool IsSystem { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my (incorrect) implementation attempt:

```
public class APEditViewModel : IUserDefinedListEditViewModel<APEntryEditViewModel>
{
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public IList<APEntryEditViewModel> UserDefinedListEntries { get; set; } = new List<APEntryEditViewModel>();
}

public class APEntryEditViewModel : IUserDefinedListEntryEditViewModel<APModel>
{
    public string Display { get; set; }
    public APModel UserDefinedListEntry { get; set; }
}

public class BaseUserDefinedListModel : IBaseUserDefinedListModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Name field is required.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSystem { get; set; }
}

public class APModel : BaseUserDefinedListModel
{
    public string NewValue { get; set; }
}
```

The main error I'm getting at the moment is in the APEditViewModel, here is the (cut down) error:

```
The type 'APEntryEditViewModel' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the
generic type or method 'IUserDefinedListEditViewModel<T>'. There is no 
implicit reference conversion from 'APEntryEditViewModel' to 
'IUserDefinedListEntryEditViewModel<IBaseUserDefinedListModel>'.
```

I'm not sure whether I need this level of generic interfaces, but from my research and experiments, I believe I do. I'm just not quite getting there and I'm thinking that the `IUserDefinedListEditViewModel` interface needing a type in the type interface (`IUserDefinedListEntryEditViewModel`) seems wrong.

Sorry that I'm not making myself that clear, it's quite tricky to explain because I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, so any questions I'll try and answer/update my question.

Comment: An interface should not be implemented by classes.  It is a method for inserting and extracting data from a class.  I think you want to make  IBaseUserDefinedListModel a class instead of an interface.

Comment: @jdweng `An interface should not be implemented by classes`? You may want to rephrase that

Comment: "An interface should not be implemented by classes." that sounds rather confusing. Do you care to elaborate on this one?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto "An interface can only be implemented by a class." An interface can also be implemented by structs.

Comment: @ikkentim I use structs so little lately that I forget about that, thanks though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `IUserDefinedListEditViewModel` interface to:

```
public interface IUserDefinedListEditViewModel<T1,T2> 
           where T1 : IUserDefinedListEntryEditViewModel<T2> 
           where T2 : IBaseUserDefinedListModel
```

After that, and update the implementation in `APEditViewModel`:

```
public class APEditViewModel : IUserDefinedListEditViewModel<APEntryEditViewModel, APModel>
```

---

The error indicates that with the generic constraint

```
where T : IUserDefinedListEntryEditViewModel<IBaseUserDefinedListModel>
```

**only** `IUserDefinedListEntryEditViewModel<IBaseUserDefinedListModel>` and types which implement this interface will be accepted as `T`. If you want any `IBaseUserDefinedListModel` to be accepted in the type parameter of `T`, you need to make it generic as well.

Comment: This worked exactly how I wanted it to, I knew I was close... ish! Just one small thing, the comma between the where on the first interface type isn't required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give us the whole business scenario for expecting the right design suggestions.

As of above examples the issue is: 
Your defined interface::

```
interface IUserDefinedListEditViewModel<T> where T : IUserDefinedListEntryEditViewModel<IBaseUserDefinedListModel>
```

But while calling you are passing APEntryEditViewModel as Interface specific type. Which is wrong with OOPS.

To successfully compile this your

APEntryEditViewModel must be an implimentation of IUserDefinedListEntryEditViewModel